# Spamassassin spam score and block configuration?

Tags: malware, spamassasin, amavis

I've searched in the community and Google for this topic. There hasn't been a precise answer.

I wanted to see the spam scores in the mail.log or syslog for Spamassassin running on my Linux server. It used to.

I've looked at files in both /etc/amavis and /etc/spamassassin.

The system is currently deleting spams and infected mails. I'd like to change that behavior.

When I look at the file that should define it (20-debian-defaults), it contradicts the actual behaviour (i.e. spam is actually deleted instead of the configured passed).

I am running Debian distro, Jessie.

Thanks, Caesar.